# How to link library in CLion

Tags: linux, c++, g++

I'm trying to use NTL library for ZZ class, and would like to use dedicated functions. Unfortunately during compilation I'm getting a lot of errors:

```
[100%] Linking CXX executable hpc5
CMakeFiles/hpc5.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `findX(NTL::ZZ, NTL::ZZ, NTL::ZZ)':
/home/rooter/CLionProjects/hpc5/main.cpp:44: undefined reference to `find_xi(NTL::ZZ, NTL::ZZ)'
/home/rooter/CLionProjects/hpc5/main.cpp:57: undefined reference to `chinese_remainder(NTL::ZZ*, NTL::ZZ*, NTL::ZZ)'
/home/rooter/CLionProjects/hpc5/main.cpp:58: undefined reference to `NTL::operator<<(std::ostream&, NTL::ZZ const&)'
CMakeFiles/hpc5.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `NTL::ZZ::ZZ(NTL::ZZ const&)':
/usr/include/NTL/ZZ.h:58: undefined reference to `_ntl_gcopy(void*, void**)'
CMakeFiles/hpc5.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `NTL::ZZ::operator=(NTL::ZZ const&)':
/usr/include/NTL/ZZ.h:73: undefined reference to `_ntl_gcopy(void*, void**)'
CMakeFiles/hpc5.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `NTL::ZZ::operator=(long)':
/usr/include/NTL/ZZ.h:75: undefined reference to `_ntl_gintoz(long, void**)'
```

I have installed libntl-dev on my linux mint, added `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -lntl" )` to my `CMakeLists.txt` and set CMake option `-lntl` and it has no effect. How can I link this library?

My CMakeLists.txt contains:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(hpc5)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -lntl" )

add_executable(hpc5 main.cpp)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to link to a runtime library using CMake, you need to use [target_link_libraries](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/target_link_libraries.html) command. For example, you may change your CMakeLists.txt file as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(hpc5)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall" )

add_executable(hpc5 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(hpc5 ntl)
```

This is assuming CMake is able to find the NTL library in your system.

EDIT : Fix executable name typo.